# Loop stopped after arriving to a decision

Tags: python

For example I have below input where I previously using my loop function to loop each element in a list of dictionary:

Code:

```
a =[[{"new":[{"name":"rule"}]}, {"new":[{"name":"king"}]}, {"find":"thanks"}, {"nothing":"cool"}]]
for x in a:
    for xx in x:
        if any(xxx["name"] == "rule" for xxx in xx.get("new", [])):
            try:
                print(["success"])
            except:
                print(["fail"])

Below is just an example of the real dataset output after returning all the thing. It is not `["success"]` or `["fail"]` because this is just an example to show what my problem in the code.


["something"]
["nothing"]
["just"]
["for"]
None
None
["showing"]
None
["example"]

I understand that since the json file has no "new" key for certain dictionaries so it will return None. But I would Like to replace this None to string "Not Found". I tried many methods to modify my code but always the return will become very weird.
```

I tried this code:

```
for x in a:
    for xx in x:
        if xx.get("new") is None:
            return ["Not getting"]
        if any(xxx == "name" for xxx in xx.get("new", [])):
            try:
                return["success"]
            except:
                return["fail"]
```

and my return is

```
["Not getting"]
["Not getting"]
["Not getting"]
["Not getting"]
["Not getting"]
["Not getting"]
["Not getting"]
["Not getting"]
```

even when there is `"new"` in the dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is doing what you are telling it to. `return` means return. You may be trying to run before you can walk but here's my best interpretation of what you are trying to do. Note the use of names that are as meaningful as I can make them - naming variables will really help you.

```
a = [[{"new": "name"}, {"new": "king"}, {"find": "thanks"}, {"nothing": "cool"}]]


def loop_example(list_of_lists_of_dict):
    for list_of_dict in list_of_lists_of_dict:
        for dictionary in list_of_dict:
            if "name" == dictionary.get("new", []):
                print("success for {}".format(dictionary))
            else:
                print("fail for {}".format(dictionary))

# loop_example(a) yields:
# success for {'new': 'name'}
# fail for {'new': 'king'}
# fail for {'find': 'thanks'}
# fail for {'nothing': 'cool'}


# As a comprehension
def comprehension_example(list_of_lists_of_dict):
    return [("success" if "name" == dictionary.get("new") else "fail")
            for list_of_dict in list_of_lists_of_dict for dictionary in list_of_dict]

# comprehension_example(a) yields:
# ['success', 'fail', 'fail', 'fail']
```